# SQL IF or CASE in IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Users are entering data into my "track" table from an .aspx page.  They are entering a series of dates for different activities and checking a box if they want to be reminded of that date.  The specific issue I have at the moment is limiting the columns in my IN statement:

```
SELECT [id], [name], MIN([DATE]) AS [MinDate] 
FROM track UNPIVOT ([DATE] FOR d IN ([date1],[date2],[date2])) unpvt
GROUP BY [id], [name]
```

I only want to include `date1` if column `date1chk`'s value is `1`.  Likewise for `date2` if `date2chk` is "1", etc.  Otherwise that `date#` column is not included in the IN.

After this my challenge is to be able to update the table such that, for example, `date2chk` is set from `1` to `0` for a specific record if, for example, `date2` was the minimum.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated -- this is proving to be one of the harder issues I've dealt with.

EDIT (thank you for the feedback):

#### Data

```
ID       Date1       Date1Chk         Date2      Date2Chk       Date3        Date3Chk
0     2013-01-15        0          2013-02-01       1        2013-02-10         1
1     2013-02-05        1          2013-02-05       1        2013-02-10         0
```

#### Desired Result

```
ID    MinDate
0    2013-02-01
1    2013-02-05
```

Assuming I can get this result, I am not certain how I would update the table.  For example, in the "desired result" ID 1 is returning a minimum value that exists for both [Date1] and [Date2]; I would want the user to halt reminders on the first instance, so [Date1Chk] would be set to 0 (not [Date2Chk]).

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Word problems are tedious and there is no way for us to validate that our potential solutions get you the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `unpivot` into a subquery, so you can grab the name of the column.  Then a `where` clause solves your problem:

```
select id, name, min([date]) as mindate
from (SELECT [id], [name], d, [DATE]
      FROM track
      UNPIVOT ([DATE] FOR d IN ([date1], [date2], [date2])) unpvt
    ) t
where (d = 'date1' and datecheck1 = 1) or
      (d = 'date2' and datecheck2 = 1) or
      (d = 'date3' and datecheck3 = 1)
GROUP BY [id], [name]
```

To get the specific date, use `row_number()` instead of `group by`:

```
select id, name, [date] as mindate
from (select id, name, [date],
             row_number() over (partition by id, name order by [date]) as seqnum
      from (SELECT [id], [name], d, [DATE]
            FROM track
            UNPIVOT ([DATE] FOR d IN ([date1], [date2], [date2])) unpvt
          ) t
      where (d = 'date1' and datecheck1 = 1) or
            (d = 'date2' and datecheck2 = 1) or
            (d = 'date3' and datecheck3 = 1)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works great.  Is there a way to tell which date column (in "d") the minimum date is coming from as part of this query?

Comment: Disregard my question, I see I can pull in the 'd' column at the top level.  By the way, to get this query running I had to add 'datecheck1', 'datecheck2' and 'datecheck3' to the subquery SELECT statement

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CROSS APPLY.. VALUES` to unpivot the data rather than the `UNPIVOT` function, this allows you to unpivot to muliple columns:

```
SELECT  ID, MinDate = MIN(Date)
FROM    track
        CROSS APPLY
        (   VALUES
                (Date1, date1chk),
                (Date2, date2chk),
                (Date3, date3chk)
        ) t (Date, datechk)
WHERE   Datechk = 1
GROUP BY ID;
```

In order to get the name of the column that contains the min date you can change the cross apply slightly to select the `TOP 1` rather than using `MIN`:

```
SELECT  ID, Name, MinDate = Date
FROM    track
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Date, datechk, Name
            FROM    (VALUES
                        (Date1, date1chk, 'Date1'),
                        (Date2, date2chk, 'Date2'),
                        (Date3, date3chk, 'Date3')
                    ) t (Date, datechk, Name)
            WHERE   Datechk = 1
            ORDER BY Date
        ) t;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d73c0f/6)**

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I was able to get this to work as well.  Is there a way to identify which column the min(date) is coming from (Date1, or Date2 in my 'desired result')?